# Check for installed program on windows using Java?

Tags: java, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if a program is installed on system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439984/how-to-check-if-a-program-is-installed-on-system)

I need to check whether a specific program is installed or not on my system. For example, my program needs to check whether **FireFox** is installed in my system.
If a program is installed , then i want to find the **installation directory** of that specific program.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175683/to-check-installed-software-using-a-program) but this is not in java.
I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439984/how-to-check-if-a-program-is-installed-on-system) but still i am unable to solve this

Comment: What problems are you having with the solutions provided? You'll have to read the windows registry to do what you want, and the solutions you linked to do exactly that.

Comment: `i read this but still i am unable to solve this` - what did you try and where did you fail? If you do not clarify - then your question is an exact duplicate.

Comment: Question #2439984 answers your question. What about the answer there don't you like?

Comment: what dont you understand from the previous question? installed software is queried from registry

Comment: yeh a possible duplicate, Thanks Problem solved. using Jregistrykey

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every software (say Firefox) creates it's entry under the path

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

Firefox also creates it under the same path.
In my machine

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Mozilla Firefox5.0.1(x86 en-US)
```

is path for that.

Existance of this path confirms that firefox is installed on machine.
For the installation directory, read the value of key named 'InstallLocation' under above mentioned path for Firefox.