# how to check mongodb installed or not programatically in java

Tags: java, node.js, mongodb

How to check mongodb installed or not in local server through programatically? using java.

I've searched in google before posting a question, I got, we can check the mongo server is running or not, if its throwing any exception we can decide mongo server is not running based on exception.

```
Mongo m = new Mongo( "localhost" , 27017 );
  // and
 DB db = m.getDB( "mydb" );
```

How can we check mongo installation in local server using Java?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check for installed program on windows using Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860968/check-for-installed-program-on-windows-using-java)

Comment: try running command in shell.and capture the output.

Comment: Why the node.js tag?

Comment: I'll check Robin Suggestion,  Can you please more clear? @ Arunesh Singh