# Making Process Class Dynamic

Tags: java

so I am a new programmer, I have been programming for about, probably a little over one month now. I am developing a fun program that asks for a username and password, once correct, the program allows the user to enter a command that can do something. I have found that using the Process class, and using the code Runtime.getRuntime().exec(""); opens a application, but is static in the sense that it the directory may not be the same for every person who uses it. How can I make this dynamic? How can I make it so the user can input their directory or even the program can detect the directory by itself?

Some code from my main class:

```
while (caseValidation.caseCheckFlag == true) {
        caseValidation.SetCase();
            if (caseValidation.GetCase().equalsIgnoreCase("internet")) 
            {
                System.out.println("Command executed!");
                intCMD.fetchInternet();
            }
            else if (caseValidation.GetCase().equalsIgnoreCase("spotify")) 
            {
                System.out.println("Command executed!");
                musCMD.fetchSpotify();
            }
            else if (caseValidation.GetCase().equalsIgnoreCase("changeUsername")) 
            {
                //code here
            }
            else if (caseValidation.GetCase().equalsIgnoreCase("changePass")) 
            {
                //code here
            }
            else if (caseValidation.GetCase().equalsIgnoreCase("pictures")) 
            {
                //code here
            }
            else if (caseValidation.GetCase().equalsIgnoreCase("videos")) 
            {
                //code here
            }
            else if (caseValidation.GetCase().equalsIgnoreCase("music")) 
            {
                //code here
            }
            else if (caseValidation.GetCase().equalsIgnoreCase("documents")) 
            {
                //code here
            }
            // more cmds here in the future
```

InternetCMD Class:

```
public class InternetCMD {

public void fetchInternet() throws IOException {
    Process internet = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe");
}
```

}

Thanks for any advice in advance! :D

Comment: Well great my post got posted twice.. T.T

Comment: Check the accepted answer in this post. It may offer some insight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860968/check-for-installed-program-on-windows-using-java

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ProcessBuilder` instead of `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`. Process builder has a directory method, which sets the working directory for the process.

From Java Doc:

> Sets this process builder's working directory. Subprocesses
>   subsequently started by this object's start() method will use this as
>   their working directory. The argument may be null -- this means to use
>   the working directory of the current Java process, usually the
>   directory named by the system property user.dir, as the working
>   directory of the child process.