# How to check if a program is downloaded (Python)

Tags: python, winreg

I am making a program in Python which I'll send to other people in our company. The aim of the program is to show which programs are downloaded and not from a list. The problem is that the program is not installed in the same place on every device.

How can I check if a program is downloaded or not?

Comment: In other words, you want to check if there are unwanted programs installed?

Comment: No just to check if there are the programs downloaded which i have to download otherwise @wernersbacher

Comment: To check for downloaded programs you have to scan the whole drive space for files with a particular name (or name pattern), content part or hash value.

Comment: If its properly installed, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175683/to-check-installed-software-using-a-program). Otherwise you have to scan all folders where the files might be and check if the found executables are from a program you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only found this:

```
import os    
os.path.exists(c:\.......)
```